# Only last frame is shown in gif when converting list of images to gif using Pillow in python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to create a mosaic jpg using different images that act like small tile images. I can get the final mosaic saved properly, but I am also trying to create a gif of the process where the mosaic is being created by saving the snapshots of each mosaic in the loop by using a list, but when i create the gif, I can only see the last frame. Help pls. Thank you!

```
from PIL import Image
import sys
mosaic = Image.new('RGB', (int(tilesX * tileHeight), int(tilesY * tileHeight)))
mosaicSnapList = []
count = 0
for x in range(0, width, pixelsPerTile):
  for y in range(0, height, pixelsPerTile):
    avg_color = findAverageImageColorInBox(baseImage, x, y, pixelsPerTile, pixelsPerTile)
    replacement = findBestTile(df_tiles, avg_color["avg_r"], avg_color["avg_g"], avg_color["avg_b"])

    tile = DISCOVERY.getTileImage(replacement["fileName"].values[0], tileHeight)
    mosaic.paste(tile, (int(x / pixelsPerTile) * tileHeight, int(y / pixelsPerTile) * tileHeight))
    mosaicSnapList.append(mosaic)
    
  
  # Print out a progress message:
  curRow = int((x / pixelsPerTile) + 1)
  pct = (curRow / tilesX) * 100
  sys.stdout.write(f'\r  ...progress: {curRow * tilesY} / {tilesX * tilesY} ({pct:.2f}%)')

##  FUNCTION TO CONVERT LIST OF IMAGES TO GIF  ##
mosaicSnapList[0].save("try.gif",format='GIF',SAVE_ALL=True,append_images=mosaicSnapList[1:], duration=400, loop=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `save_all=True`, rather than `SAVE_ALL=True` in:

```
mosaicSnapList[0].save("try.gif",format='GIF',SAVE_ALL=True ...
```